# Send email with Swiftmailer in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

Hi I'm using Swiftmailer for sending email in my project symfony2 for the contact form.
When I try it in **dev** environment it works fine, but in In **prod** I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' 
with message ' in C:\wamp\www\saaytu_symfony\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 386

Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", 
with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. 
Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 lo18sm27016542wic.1 - gsmtp "
in C:\wamp\www\saaytu_symfony\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 386
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: This looks like you haven't configured SWIFT mailer in your prod conf, only in your dev conf. Where did you enter the credentials for the mail server?

Comment: Thank. I configure swift in config.yml. It must work because config_prod.yml import config.yml. I don't know why it isn't work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the relevant part of your config, just exclude the sensitive data.

Comment: Are you sure, that you use the same PARAMETERS.YML for dev/prod? Probably different credentials in parameters.yml

Comment: Ok it's work cool. The parameters are the config_dev.yml not in config.yml. I have just copying it the config_prod.yml.

Comment: How can i mark it solve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark this then:

Are you sure, that you use the same PARAMETERS.YML for dev/prod? Probably different credentials in parameters.yml.

Comment: Ok it's work. I have the configuration in config_dev.yml. I have just copy it in the conf_prod.yml. Cool thank you everobody.